# OpenSearch `search_as_you_type` index_prefix field does not return document with `match` query but does with `match_phrase` query

Tags: elasticsearch, search, full-text-search, opensearch, amazon-opensearch

I have created a mapping in OpenSearch that looks as follows:

```
"mappings": {
        "properties": {
            "name": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                    "prefixed_split":{
                        "type":"search_as_you_type",
                        "analyzer":"asciifold_separated"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

The `asciifold_separated` analyzer looks as follows:

```
"asciifold_separated": {
    "char_filter": [],
    "tokenizer": "standard",
    "filter": [
      "lowercase",
      "asciifolding"
    ]
}
```

I used the `_bulk` end point to store some documents. One of the documents I stored is as follows:

```
{ "index" : { "_id": 1 }}
{ "name":"David Silva" }
```

When I analyze the vectors I am getting the following response:

```
{
    "_index": "test_local",
    "_id": "1",
    "_version": 2,
    "found": true,
    "took": 23,
    "term_vectors": {
        "name": {
            "terms": {
                "david": {
                    "term_freq": 1
                },
                "silva": {
                    "term_freq": 1
                }
            }
        },
        "name.prefixed_split._2gram": {
            "terms": {
                "david silva": {
                    "term_freq": 1
                }
            }
        },
        "name.prefixed_split._index_prefix": {
            "terms": {
                "d": {
                    "term_freq": 1
                },
                "da": {
                    "term_freq": 1
                },
                "dav": {
                    "term_freq": 1
                },
                "davi": {
                    "term_freq": 1
                },
                "david": {
                    "term_freq": 1
                },
                "david ": {
                    "term_freq": 1
                },
                "david s": {
                    "term_freq": 1
                },
                "david si": {
                    "term_freq": 1
                },
                "david sil": {
                    "term_freq": 1
                },
                "david silv": {
                    "term_freq": 1
                },
                "david silva": {
                    "term_freq": 1
                },
                "david silva ": {
                    "term_freq": 1
                },
                "s": {
                    "term_freq": 1
                },
                "si": {
                    "term_freq": 1
                },
                "sil": {
                    "term_freq": 1
                },
                "silv": {
                    "term_freq": 1
                },
                "silva": {
                    "term_freq": 1
                },
                "silva ": {
                    "term_freq": 1
                },
                "silva  ": {
                    "term_freq": 1
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, the `name.prefixed_split._index_prefix` sub field which is created by the `search_as_you_type` field type has an entry for `sil`, but when I search for the sil entry in a match query, it does not return any document

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool":{
            "should": [
                {
                    "match": {
                        "name.prefixed_split._index_prefix": "SIL"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    "from": 0,
    "size": 10000,
    "sort": [],
    "aggs": {}
}
```

the result is:

```
{
    "took": 7,
    "timed_out": false,
    "_shards": {
        "total": 1,
        "successful": 1,
        "skipped": 0,
        "failed": 0
    },
    "hits": {
        "total": {
            "value": 0,
            "relation": "eq"
        },
        "max_score": null,
        "hits": []
    }
}
```

However, when I use the `match_phrase` query, I get the desired result

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool":{
            "should": [
                {
                    "match_phrase": {
                        "name.prefixed_split._index_prefix": "SIL"
                        
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    "from": 0,
    "size": 10000,
    "sort": [],
    "aggs": {}
}
```

result:

```
{
    "took": 2,
    "timed_out": false,
    "_shards": {
        "total": 1,
        "successful": 1,
        "skipped": 0,
        "failed": 0
    },
    "hits": {
        "total": {
            "value": 1,
            "relation": "eq"
        },
        "max_score": 1.9891725,
        "hits": [
            {
                "_index": "test_local",
                "_id": "1",
                "_score": 1.9891725,
                "_source": {
                    "name": "David Silva"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I have a couple of questions regarding these outputs:

1. From my understanding, the only difference between the `match` and `match_phrase` query is that in `match_phrase` the query is tokenised and the last token is searched as a prefix while the rest of he tokens are searched in exact order. But for a single search term like "sil", the tokenisation process should produce a single token "sil". I see in the term vectors, there is already a term "sil" present in the `name.prefixed_split._index_prefix` sub field.
   Why does the match query not match the "sil" to the entry "sil" which is present in the term vectors? why does it need to be searched as a prefix?
2. If you observe the field `name.prefixed_split._index_prefix`, after the last entry of "silva", there are 2 extra whitespaces present. Where are those whitespaces coming from? The same is true for the entry "david silva ". Where is the extra whitespace coming from?